# AppLocalizations.of(context) returns not a constant expression

Tags: flutter, localization

I've followed [Googles Flutter Internationalization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#setting-up) tutorial but does not seem to get the following to work:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
... .

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld)
      ),
   );
}
```

I get the following compile-time error:

```
lib/presentation/pages/search/search_page.dart:12:41: Error: Not a constant expression.
        child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld)
                                        ^^^^^^^
lib/presentation/pages/search/search_page.dart:12:38: Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
        child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.helloWorld)
```

It looks like `Text(data: String, .. .)` wants a constant string parameter but `Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)..` returns an optional value. But in every example,even Googles, I see this should or did work. Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

Comment: If it can't be const, it can't be const.  Just keep removing const until it works, and if you have the lint properly enabled, you'll see where you can add const back, if any.

Comment: Can you provide full source code? Error is certainly due to a const keyword somewhere in your code. Localized string can't be const.

Answer (score 2):

Your error messages do not fit your source example. And neither does your question.
To answer your question:

add the following to your `l10n.yaml` to make the `AppLocalizations.of(..)` null safe:

```
nullable-getter: false
```

regarding the error messages: remove all `const` from your code.. since your example does not contain any, I doubt that's the code where you get those error messages from.

Comment: Not sure what it was but changing it between a Container and then back to Text made it work.